# Getting session data cost in asp.net with state server

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm using the ASP.NET session state server for one of my websites. I put a user object in session because it is used a lot.

Consider the following code fragment:

```
DoSomething(SessionUser.Me.UserID)
DoSomeMore(SessionUser.Me.UserName)
```

SessionUser.Me is a static property that just does something like:

```
return (SessionUser)Session["currentuser"];
```

Now because I access SessionUser.Me 2 times (DoSomething and DoSomeMore) is .NET smart enough to not do 2 roundtrips to the stateserver and deserialize 2 times?

With other words is it equivalent in performance if I just did:

```
var user = SessionUser.Me;
DoSomething(user.UserID)
DoSomeMore(user.UserName)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session is deserialized from the state server early in the request pipeline (see [HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.acquirerequeststate.aspx), and written back to the state server when execution of the page completes (see [HttpApplication.ReleaseRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.releaserequeststate.aspx)).

Thus, you shouldn't incur a performance hit from repeated access.