# Using Variable V/s Use Session Variable Again and Again

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

This kind of weird question but I have confusion so I think better ask.

My colleague told me that if in a method if you use session variable more than once, then you should take it in a variable and use it. So is there any kind of performance enhancement if I use a variable for session and use it rather than using session variable directly again and again?

Here is My Code:

```
Public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string rotatestr)
{
  try
  {
    errorLog.ProcessMessage("FileUpload Method is Started");
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    int[][] rotateInfo = js.Deserialize<int[][]>(rotatestr);
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
      string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(General.FaxFolder + 
        Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Session["CurrentFile"]) + "/"),
        Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

      file.SaveAs(filePath);
      pdfOperation = new PdfOperationUtility();
      if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(General.FaxFolder + 
        Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Session["CurrentFile"]) + "/mearge.pdf")))
      {
                          pdfOperation.PdfSourcePath = General.FaxFolder + 
          Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Session["CurrentFile"]) + "/mearge.pdf";
      }
      else
      {
        pdfOperation.PdfSourcePath = General.FaxFolder + 
          Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Session["CurrentFile"]) + "/" + 
          Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Session["barcodeString"]) + "." + FaxFileType.pdf;
      }
      pdfOperation.PdfDestinationPath = General.FaxFolder + Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Session["CurrentFile"]) + "/";
      pdfOperation.PdfMearge(filePath, rotateInfo);
      pdfOperation.PdfSourcePath = General.FaxFolder + Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Session["CurrentFile"]) + "/mearge.pdf";
      pdfOperation.ImageOutputPath = General.FaxFolder + Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Session["CurrentFile"]) + General.splitImageFolder;
      ViewBag.filelist = pdfOperation.SplitPdfToImages(true);
    }
    errorLog.ProcessMessage("FileUpload Method is Completed");
    return this.PartialView("_EditPdf");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    errorLog.Write(ex);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
  }
}
```

Comment: It depends on the Session provider.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688457/getting-session-data-cost-in-asp-net-with-state-server

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar here is code sample.

Comment: @rene That's not my kind of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that instead of using `Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Session["CurrentFile"])` four times it's better to do `string currentFile  = (string)HttpContext.Session["CurrentFile"];` and use `currentFile` throughout the rest of the code, you're right.

From a performance standpoint you won't notice the difference (you're processing a file upload), but for readability and maintainability it's highly advisable.